# Checking DTD in a varity of XML documents to make sure they are all the same

Tags: c#, c++, xml, dtd

I was wondering how I check the DTD of a variety of XML documents to make sure they are all the same.

At the moment I am just copying and pasting the DTD from the template file, but would be great to have a small program that checks how similar txt documents are or checks a specified group of text against other documents, finds it and returns true or false etc.

This will be handy when using a mass amount of XML files.

Any pointers on ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an external doctype definition. See here a list of examples 
http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

I think this link helps more
https://supportweb.cs.bham.ac.uk/documentation/tutorials/docsystem/build/tutorials/docbooksys/segmentedhtml/ch08s02.html